# Exception coming: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss5.x

Getting below exception while running my application :

I am using jboss : 5.1.1 and jdk 1.6.

```
01:50:04,828 ERROR [[HelloWorld]] Servlet.service() for servlet HelloWorld threw exception
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.getProviderUsingServiceLoader(Provider.java:146)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:106)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
    at com.service_instance.ServiceInstance.<init>(ServiceInstance.java:50)
    at com.getBusinessApp(CMDB.java:239)
    at com.test.HelloWorld.doGet(HelloWorld.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Let m know. How to resolve this. It seems like some lib issue.

Comment: you seem to be using an incorrect subtype of `javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider`. Please post the code where you are facing this issue.

Comment: providing some code might help, e.g. CMDB line 239

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem deploying a USSD gateway with [Mobicents Jain Slee](http://www.mobicents.org/slee/intro.html), that runs on top of a JBoss AS 5.1.0 GA. The gateway has to connect to a server via SOAP, so I chose JAX-WS and generated the source code from a WSDL with [wsimport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html).
By the way, I used a similar procedure to [this one](http://www.hascode.com/2010/04/create-a-soap-client-using-the-jax-ws-maven-plugin/) to create a child Maven project and generate the java files for JAX-WS.

---

### Failed deploy with dependencies embedded on .war file

My first approach was to include all the dependencies in the .war file that is deployed in JBoss.
I think this is achieved by default in Maven, and `mvn install` will do it.
In the long run, this approach failed, but at least I needed to know the list of jar files that were included in the .war file, to copy them later in a JBoss directory.

I made a lot of troubleshooting with this approach, and had many different log errors, though the main one was this:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not a subtype
```

---

### Deploy without dependencies

#### Maven tweak

So insted, I added `<scope>provided</scope>` to the JAX-WS dependencies. Something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>
    <artifactId>istack-commons-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This produced a much lighter .war file.

#### Copy & remove jars in JBoss AS

Now, after deploying the .war file, when my SOAP client tried to connect to the Web Service, and it throwed the exception:

```
org.jboss.ws.metadata.wsdl.WSDLException: Invalid default namespace: null
at org.jboss.ws.tools.wsdl.WSDLDefinitionsFactory.parse(WSDLDefinitionsFactory.java:134)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.ServiceMetaData.getWsdlDefinitions(ServiceMetaData.java:293)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSClientMetaDataBuilder.buildMetaData(JAXWSClientMetaDataBuilder.java:84)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegateImpl.<init>(ServiceDelegateImpl.java:138)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:63)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:79)
at org.ortelius.UssdServiceImplementation.<init>(UssdServiceImplementation.java:42)
at org.ortelius.OrteliusClient.sendUssdRequestToWs(OrteliusClient.java:28)
```

It seems that `javax.xml.ws.Service` calls `org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl`, but it should be calling `com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl`, so it seems there is a conflict with jar dependencies.

To avoid this problem, it was necessary to:

1. Move or delete all JBoss jar files found in `$JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed/` directory.
2. Copy the jars bundled in my initial .war file (the one of the failed deploy) to `$JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed/` directory.
   all the jars bundled in my .war file.

That basically made it.

---

#### Final notes

I have to confess that to find this out was a *real pain*, and it took me about four days to get this up & running.
I made a lot of troubleshooting with the jar dependencies, checking JBoss logs, remote debugging, comparing Java packages & classes versions, searching for jars online and reading many articles from JBoss manuals, blogs, StackOverflow, JavaRanch, etc...

The SOAP client was really simple, but the **deployment in JBoss was pretty problematic**.
My solution is not very orthodox, since it depends greatly on the jar files dependencies.
So I'm not sure if it will work for everyone.

Regards.

Comment: I have the same problem on Wildfly. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158821/wildfly-how-to-use-jaxws-ri-instead-of-apache-cxf-webservice-client-only. Have you some new ideas? The problem is that I cannot "manipulate" the Wildfly itself, since all is running in cloud where I have no access to manipulate the application server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch class loaders.

Grab classloader from your Service class and reset after the call.

```
    final ClassLoader targetClassLoader = ServiceXY.class.getClassLoader();
    final Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
    final ClassLoader contextClassLoader = currentThread.getContextClassLoader();
    try {
           currentThread.setContextClassLoader(targetClassLoader);
           //here call your Service 
    } finally {
           currentThread.setContextClassLoader(contextClassLoader);
    }
```

JEE libs have been removed with Java 9, JEE-specific libs / implementations must now be made available by the application via thirdparty libraries - e.g. jaxws-api.jar and jaxws-rt.jar. This code of JEE libs often still expects to be part of the jre system library and with that of the application classloader - but it isn't anymore. So if service classloader `ServiceXY.class.getClassLoader()` and your application classloader `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` are different you need to switch for the request.