# org.jboss.ws.metadata.wsdl.WSDLException_ Invalid default namespace_ null

Tags: jboss5.x, wsimport

I have a WSDL and have generated code using wsimport. I have written code to the access the web service & trying to test it. It works on Tomcat, but on JBOSS 5.1 GA, it gives following error:

org.jboss.ws.metadata.wsdl.WSDLException_ Invalid default namespace_ null

I have spent 3 days figuring out the problem with no luck. One os the solutions that I tried involved jaxws-rt files & working with the jboss endorsed directory, but I am not sure which jars that need to be replaced, so I am still stuck.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you already fixed this issue, but just in case someone is interested.

I had the same problem deploying a USSD gateway with [Mobicents Jain Slee](http://www.mobicents.org/slee/intro.html), that runs on top of a JBoss AS 5.1.0 GA. The gateway has to connect to a server via SOAP, so I chose JAX-WS and generated the source code from a WSDL with [wsimport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html).
By the way, I used a similar procedure to [this one](http://www.hascode.com/2010/04/create-a-soap-client-using-the-jax-ws-maven-plugin/) to create a child Maven project and generate the java files for JAX-WS.

---

### Failed deploy with dependencies embedded on .war file

My first approach was to include all the dependencies in the .war file that is deployed in JBoss.
I think this is achieved by default in Maven, and `mvn install` will do it.
In the long run, this approach failed, but at least I needed to know the list of jar files that were included in the .war file, to copy them later in a JBoss directory.

I made a lot of troubleshooting with this approach, and had many different log errors, though the main one was this:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not a subtype
```

That can be found in [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624719/exception-coming-java-util-serviceconfigurationerror).

---

### Deploy without dependencies

#### Maven tweak

So insted, I added `<scope>provided</scope>` to the JAX-WS dependencies. Something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>
    <artifactId>istack-commons-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This produced a much lighter .war file.

#### Copy & remove jars in JBoss AS

Now, after deploying the .war file, when my SOAP client tries to connect to the Web Service, it throws the exception mentioned in the question:

```
org.jboss.ws.metadata.wsdl.WSDLException: Invalid default namespace: null
at org.jboss.ws.tools.wsdl.WSDLDefinitionsFactory.parse(WSDLDefinitionsFactory.java:134)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.ServiceMetaData.getWsdlDefinitions(ServiceMetaData.java:293)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSClientMetaDataBuilder.buildMetaData(JAXWSClientMetaDataBuilder.java:84)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegateImpl.<init>(ServiceDelegateImpl.java:138)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:63)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:79)
at org.ortelius.UssdServiceImplementation.<init>(UssdServiceImplementation.java:42)
at org.ortelius.OrteliusClient.sendUssdRequestToWs(OrteliusClient.java:28)
```

It seems that `javax.xml.ws.Service` calls `org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl`, but it should be calling `com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl`, so it seems there is a conflict with jar dependencies.

To avoid this problem, it was necessary to:

1. Move or delete all JBoss jar files found in `$JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed/` directory.
2. Copy the jars bundled in my initial .war file (the one of the failed deploy) to `$JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed/` directory.
   all the jars bundled in my .war file.

That basically made it.

---

#### Final notes

I have to confess that to find this out was a *real pain*, and it took me about four days to get this up & running.
I made a lot of troubleshooting with the jar dependencies, checking JBoss logs, remote debugging, comparing Java packages & classes versions, searching for jars online and reading many articles from JBoss manuals, blogs, StackOverflow, JavaRanch, etc...

The SOAP client was really simple, but the **deployment in JBoss was pretty problematic**.
My solution is not very orthodox, since it depends greatly on the jar files dependencies.
So I'm not sure if it will work for everyone.

Regards.