# Error running my spring app

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Below is the log. When I added following maven dependency, my Spring application started to show the errors. Now, it does not start.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
    <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>policy</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

It caused following error:

```
    Aug 31, 2015 12:50:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'arbapiService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.anet.api.arb.ARBAPIServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl could not be instantiated
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.anet.api.arb.ARBAPIServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl could not be instantiated
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
        ... 22 more
    Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.getProviderUsingServiceLoader(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at net.authorize.services.Service.<init>(Service.java:53)
        v2.runtime.reflect.Lister.getImplClass(Lister.java:116)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister.create(Lister.java:102)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayProperty.<init>(ArrayProperty.java:26)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.<init>(ArrayERProperty.java:45)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:88)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:142)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:407)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:426)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I found this might be version related issue of these libs . How to resolve this? I am using apache tomcat 7 and spring 3 with maven 3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception coming: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624719/exception-coming-java-util-serviceconfigurationerror)

Comment: no bro I am using apache not jboss @hagrawal and the error is not same either

Comment: Ok .. Give me some time and do some investigation for your issue ..Meanwhile like you have guessed, verify one more time that all required JARs are in place and most important thing - they are in classpath for runtime reference ..

Comment: Yes they are in runtime .. I am using maven .. Ok thanks