# Wildfly's JAXWS implementation seems to ignore bindingProvider property com.sun.xml.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory

Tags: java, ssl, soap, jax-ws, wildfly

My environment is a Maven Project and Wildfly (8.2.1) as Application Server. What I need is to connect wihin a incoming REST call to a third party server using SOAP. I need SSL Client Authentication; therefore, I have my own KeyStore and TrustStore. I create therefore my own SSLContext and need to let the WebService use this SSLContext.

There is a problem with Wildfly and it's used implementation of JAXWS (Apache CXF?) - I described it here (but with another aproach to solve the problem; therefore *it is not a duplicate post!*):
 [Wildfly: How to use JAXWS-RI instead of Apache CXF (WebService client only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158821/wildfly-how-to-use-jaxws-ri-instead-of-apache-cxf-webservice-client-only)

One of the main problems seems to be that JAXWS used in Wildfly seems to ignore setting the own SSLContext with property `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory`:

```
MyWS_Service service = new MyWS_Service(null, new QName("http://...", "MyWS"));
MyWS port = service.getMyWSSOAP();

BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://hostname:443/.../...");

// the following setting is ignored!
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", mySslSocketFactory);

// in some posts, we see that we need to eliminate 'internal' in the property. This does not help!
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", mySslSocketFactory);
```

The proof that it is ignored is that if I use `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(mySslSocketFactory)` to set the SSLContext, it does work - means the SSL connection is established thanks to the imported root CA to the customized TrustStore setup in the SSLContext.

If we look at other posts (e.g. [How to programmatically set the SSLContext of a JAX-WS client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001102/how-to-programmatically-set-the-sslcontext-of-a-jax-ws-client)) this property **should** work (even for Wildfly according some comments there). But it does not in my situation. What can be the cause of this?

Comment: As described in my comment on your previous post I really think the problem is the `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory` reference. Did you see this comment? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19587610/152794

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is definitively ignored because Wildfly uses CXF. I also found a solution which I will post next week here.. What I did not understand is that someone posted that it should work in Wildfly with this property set: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23053824/4106030.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is definitifely that Apache CXF ignores

```
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(
    "com.sun.xml.[internal.]ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", mySslSocketFactory);
```

in oposite to some comments some where.

So my final solution is to programmatically setup the `HTTPConduit` used (rather than set a config in a `cxf.xml` file).

```
// Set custom SSLContext.
HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(port).getConduit();
TLSClientParameters tlsClientParameters = new TLSClientParameters();
tlsClientParameters.setSSLSocketFactory(customSSLContext.getSocketFactory());
conduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsClientParameters);
```

I hope that this helps someone having similar issues...

Comment: Please, how do you did that? If I try to use the TLSClientParameters class I get the error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/configuration/jsse/TLSClientParameters". I'm using the jbossws-cxf-client artifact on my POM .

Answer (score 6):

Apache CXF ignores the JAX-WS properties. You can specify the TLS Client Parameters programmatically the following way:

```java
TLSClientParameters tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();
tlsParams.setUseHttpsURLConnectionDefaultSslSocketFactory(false);
tlsParams.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(TLSClientParameters.class.getName(), tlsParams);
```

Comment: Vladimir it works ! I wonder where did you find it.

Comment: I am usin Wildfly 22 and it's throwing exception in runtime: ClassNotFound for TLSClientParameters. Any solution?

Answer (score 4):

When using the `HTTPConduit` solution for Wildfly 10 I had to add `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
  <module name="org.jboss.ws.cxf.jbossws-cxf-client" services="import" />

  <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl" export="true">  
       <imports>  
            <include path="META-INF" />  
            <include path="META-INF/cxf" />  
            <include path="META-INF/services" />  
       </imports>         
  </module>   
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution to Widfly 8.2.1:

1) Add the file src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider with the line com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl inside

2) Add the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

3) Add the SSLSocketFactory this way:

```
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", mySslSocketFactory);
```